# Is there a python web browser that supports user login?

Tags: python, browser

I want to login to a website via python, is there a browser or some wrapper that could do the job.

Comment: What do you want to do after you log in? Logging in is pretty useless on its own.

Comment: To get login user only data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Websites determine if someone is logged in or not using what are called cookies. In order to masquerade as a logged in user, all you need to do is to supply the Cookie in your request headers. Any python module to handle web requests can do this. Below is sample code using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/)

```
import requests

url = 'www.targetsite.com/page/i/need/'
headers = { 'Connection' : 'keep-alive',
            'Header' : 'header-value',
            'Cookie' : 'CookieFieldName=CookieValue'
          }
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print r.content
```

Comment: When do I supply the user info, without it I could not get what I want.

Comment: Log in with a browser, and then view cookies stored in your browser. Or simply view the headers your browser sends when you request the page you need using something like [LiveHTTPHeaders](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/) (also exists for Chrome). Then when making the request from python, supply the same headers.